# Start mainActivity if user login sucesses

Tags: android

Here is a simulation of user credentials checking, most of this code was generated by Android Studio. if the user:pass does not exist, it goes to registration, but i am not sure where am i supposed to send the user to main activity. please take a look at `checking mail & pass` part.

```
/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
 // checking mail & pass
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);

            }

        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }

}
```

where do i start the main activity after the user:pass is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found it now.
inside `if (success)`

Comment: Yes, `if(success) start new activity here`

Comment: but i found out now that success is true even if the credentials are wrong. why doesnt it go to register activity?

Comment: I do not see where you set the value of success

Answer (score 2):

Try This One....
This will work surely..

/**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
 // checking mail & pass
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);

            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainHomePageActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, but i need `mPasswordView.requestFocus();` in case the email is true & pass wrong, so it returns and lets the user retry

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

    try {
        // Simulate network access.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
// checking mail & pass
    for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
        String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
        if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
            // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
            return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);

        }

    }

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);

    if (success) {
    // TODO: register the new account here.
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    } else {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
        mPasswordView.requestFocus();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    mAuthTask = null;
    showProgress(false);
}

}
```